# Reference value from mutliple columns and rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Having an issue where by I am trying to return a value from 2 data validation.

My sheet is as follows:

[image]

So i created 2 dropdown fields via Data Validation and I am trying retrieve a value.

**Example 1**

Dropdown 1 is A (from row)

Dropdown 2 is H (from column)

Expected value should be 8.5

**Example 2**

Dropdown 1 is D (from row).

Dropdown 2 is F (from column)

Expected value should be 6.5

The formula I have tried is as follows:

`=VLOOKUP(O9,A1:J9,9,FALSE)`

however have had no luck.

Any ideas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use INDEX/MATCH/MATCH:

```
=INDEX($B$2:$J$9,MATCH("A",$A$2:$A$9,0),MATCH("H",$B$1:$J$1,0))
```

Comment: This is just for Example 1. Is there no way to make the column/row selection "A" and "H" dynamic based on what the user has selected in the drop down?

Comment: Yes, just replace the `"A"` and `"H"` with their respective cell reference.

Comment: Awesome! works like a charm!